# How to show the activity indicator when data is fetching from server

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I am working on apple watch application where i am using the network class for showing the data on apple watch.I want to show the activity indicator when the data is fetching after the successfully fetching the data then hide the activity indicator.Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

WatchKit doesn't have any structure like `UIActivityIndicatorView`,but you can create your own animation with images.

If your WKInterfaceController awailable to add WKInterfaceImage add it and use WKInterfaceImage's method to animate. If not, then push a WKInterfaceController and make request here.

This [tutorial](https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-animate/) is one of my best, follow it.

I used `JBWatchActivityIndicator` on [github](https://github.com/mikeswanson/JBWatchActivityIndicator) to create sequence images.

Comment: But How can we place WKInterfaceImage over the WKInterfaceTable in storyboard in watchos.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial: https://www.natashatherobot.com/watchkit-create-table/

Answer (score 0):

use this code to show activity indicator

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]     
        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;
    [activityView startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Checkout the `JBWatchActivityIndicator` project on `GitHub` that lets you generate your own image sequences: https://github.com/mikeswanson/JBWatchActivityIndicator

Comment: There is no method for displaying ActivityIndicator in WatchKit Framework. but you can try this https://github.com/timonus/WatchActivityIndicator

Comment: It only contains the GIF images.

Comment: there are not so many ways to show activity indicator in watchkit. so try to modify it according to your need you will succeed

Answer (score 0):

There is no activityIndicator in WatchKit.so use WKInterfaceImage or WKInterfaceGroup show Indicator.

```
 image.setImageNamed(your_image_folder)
 image.startAnimatingWithImages(in: NSMakeRange(0, 39), duration: 1.0, repeatCount: 0)
```

Refer the like https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612980/9110213